# Несколько модальных окон в одном magnific popup

Tags: jquery

Есть пример от самого автора плагина:

```js
// Define data for the popup
var data = [
  {
    username: "Brad Frost", // Key "username"     
    userWebsite_href: 'http://www.bradfrostweb.com',    
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1561258552/brad_frost_bigger.png',   
    userLocation: 'Pittsburgh, PA'
  },
  
  {
    username: "Paul Irish",
    userWebsite_href: 'http://paulirish.com',
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2910976341/7d972c32f3882f715ff84a67685e6acf_bigger.jpeg',
    userLocation: 'San Francisco'
  },
  
  {
    username: "Chris Coyier",
    userWebsite_href: 'http://css-tricks.com',
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1668225011/Gravatar2_bigger.png',
    userLocation: 'Palo Alto, California'
  }
];

// initalize popup
$('button').magnificPopup({ 
  key: 'my-popup', 
  items: data,
  type: 'inline',
  inline: {
    // Define markup. Class names should match key names.
    markup: '<div class="white-popup"><div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
              '<a class="mfp-userWebsite">'+
                '<div class="mfp-userAvatarUrl"></div>'+
                '<h2 class="mfp-username"></h2>'+
              '</a>'+
              '<div class="mfp-userLocation"></div>'+
            '</div>'
  },
  gallery: {
    enabled: true 
  },
  callbacks: {
    markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
      // optionally apply your own logic - modify "template" element based on data in "values"
      // console.log('Parsing:', template, values, item);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  
<button style="padding:20px;">Open popup 1</button>
```

У меня же ситуацию немного иная:

```js
// Define data for the popup
var data = [
  {
    username: "Brad Frost", // Key "username"     
    userWebsite_href: 'http://www.bradfrostweb.com',    
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1561258552/brad_frost_bigger.png',   
    userLocation: 'Pittsburgh, PA'
  },
  
  {
    username: "Paul Irish",
    userWebsite_href: 'http://paulirish.com',
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2910976341/7d972c32f3882f715ff84a67685e6acf_bigger.jpeg',
    userLocation: 'San Francisco'
  },
  
  {
    username: "Chris Coyier",
    userWebsite_href: 'http://css-tricks.com',
    userAvatarUrl_img: 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1668225011/Gravatar2_bigger.png',
    userLocation: 'Palo Alto, California'
  }
];

// initalize popup
$('button').magnificPopup({ 
  key: 'my-popup', 
  items: data,
  type: 'inline',
  inline: {
    // Define markup. Class names should match key names.
    markup: '<div class="white-popup"><div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
              '<a class="mfp-userWebsite">'+
                '<div class="mfp-userAvatarUrl"></div>'+
                '<h2 class="mfp-username"></h2>'+
              '</a>'+
              '<div class="mfp-userLocation"></div>'+
            '</div>'
  },
  gallery: {
    enabled: false
  },
  callbacks: {
    markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
      // optionally apply your own logic - modify "template" element based on data in "values"
      // console.log('Parsing:', template, values, item);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  
<button style="padding:20px;">Open popup 1</button>

<button style="padding:20px;">Open popup 2</button>

<button style="padding:20px;">Open popup 3</button>

  
  <div class="white-popup">
    
  </div>
```

Т.е. у меня есть множество button, клик по которым должен вызывать модальное с опр. данными для этого окна. Прописывать для каждой кнопки модальное - не вариант. Но разобраться как это сделать для одного окна тоже не получается.

Как для определенной кнопки открывать модальное с определенным контентом?

Comment: Вопрос ещё актуален?  На данный момент работаю с этой библиотекой, могу попробовать подсказать.